# Link to sql query (i need only rolename by roleid in query, not all the others whole query)

Tags: hyperlink, asp.net-mvc-5

```
Method:1
var rolename= from r in db.Roles
          where r.Id == model.RoleId
          select r.Name;
Method:2                    
var rolename= db.Roles.Where(r => r.Id == model.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
Method:3
 var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db);
 var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
  var rolename= roleManager.FindById(model.RoleId);
```

"i want only rolename .please tell me the right way(query) anything else."

Answer (score 0):

```
var rolename= from r in db.Roles
      where r.Id == model.RoleId
      select r.Name;
```

This will return a collection of Names which matches your where condition. the rolename's type will be `IEnumerable<string>` assuming Name's type is string. If you want only one record (First one matching the condition), you may call the `FirstOrDefault()` method.

```
string roleName=string.empty;
var firstRole= (from r in db.Roles
      where r.Id == model.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
if(firstRole!=null
{
   roleName = firstRole;
}
```

Or you can do FirstOrDefault() on a collection of strings. This will return the default value for string type, which is `null`.

```
var rolename= (from r in db.Roles
                 where r.Id == model.RoleId select r.Name).FirstOrDefault()
```

For Method 2, You are calling the `FirstOrDefault()` on the Roles collection which will give a `Role` object. You need to read the `Name` property from that.

`FirstOrDefault()` will return null if there are no records matching your where condition. So make sure to do a null check before accessing the Name Property.

```
var roleName=string.empty;
var role= db.Roles.Where(r => r.Id == model.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
if(role!=null)
{
  roleName=role.Name;
}
```

Here also you can do the `Select(d=>d.Name).FirstOrDefault()` like what we did for Method 1.

Both are correct approach. Pick the one you and your team likes.